# How to make join for the record not exist on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables: **1.Parent, 2.Child1Table and 3.Child2Table**

**Parent**

```
ParentItem    soldQty
----------------------
111            5
222           10
333            4
```

**Child1Table**

```
ParentItem    ChildItemID1    soldQty
-------------------------------------
555            551               5
222            221              10
333            331              14
```

**Child2Table**

```
ParentItem    ChildItemID2    soldQty
-------------------------------------
555            552               5
666            662              10
333            332              20
```

**Expecting output**

```
ParentItem    QtySold
---------------------
111              5  //5
222             20  //10 + 10
333             38  //4 + 14 + 20
555             10  //5 + 5
666             10  //10
```

Is it possible to achieve this using `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Why do you have two different child tables?

Comment: @jarlh Actually I have 3 child table. that's my case.

Comment: What query have you written to get your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

`UNION ALL` your tables in a derived table. `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select ParentItem, sum(soldQty) as QtySold
from
(
    select ParentItem, soldQty from Parent
    union all
    select ParentItem, soldQty from Child1Table
    union all
    select ParentItem, soldQty from Child2Table
) dt
group by ParentItem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` like:

```
DECLARE @Parent TABLE (ParentItem INT, soldQty INT);
DECLARE @Child1 TABLE (ParentItem INT, ChildItemID1 INT, soldQty INT);
DECLARE @Child2 TABLE (ParentItem INT, ChildItemID2 INT, soldQty INT);
/**/
INSERT INTO @Parent VALUES
(111, 5),
(222, 10),
(333, 4);
INSERT INTO @Child1 VALUES
(555,            551,              5),
(222,            221,              10),
(333,            331,              14);

INSERT INTO @Child2 VALUES
(555,            552,              5),
(666,            662,              10),
(333,            332,              20);

/**/
;With CTE AS (
    SELECT ParentItem, soldQty FROM @Parent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ParentItem, soldQty FROM @Child1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ParentItem, soldQty FROM @Child2
    )
SELECT ParentItem, sum(soldQty) SoldQty
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ParentItem;
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/TGM8921)**.

Answer (score 0):

As there is `ParentItem` in al the tables, simply union the data sets, then aggregate.

```
select parentitem, sum(soldqty) as qtysold
from
(
  select parentitem, soldqty from parent
  union all
  select parentitem, soldqty from child1table
  union all
  select parentitem, soldqty from child2table
) alldata
group by parentitem;
```